# Get the original file name in java?

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

In Windows os, I have a file, for example "README" .

Using java,  `File("readme").exists()` will return true

How to get the true file name, something like this:

```
  new File("readme").getTrueFileName()  //return "README"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at [`File.getCanonicalPath`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath%28%29) - that returns the "real" filename.

There's also `File.getCanonicalFile` which returns the same information but as a `File` object.

(I've just tested this with your exact situation, and it works fine.)

Comment: What about [File.getAbsolutePath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath())?

Comment: @Harry: `File.getAbsolutePath` does not resolve symlinks (or, at least, the javadocs don't mention symlinks). It only turns a relative path into an absolute one. It's not the "real" path in the sense that it can still contain symlinks.

Comment: @Cameron: The OP wants file name then why not simply use [getName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName())?

Comment: @Harry: Again, that doesn't find the filename *on disk* - it just returns the name part of the File object which has already been constructed.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: OP says he just wants file name "`new File("readme").getTrueFileName()  //return "README"`". Anyways OP has accepted your answer so may be this is what he wants and I interpreted him wrong.

Comment: @Harry: But he wants the *real filename on disk*, not the one from the original `File`. Neither `getAbsolutePath` nor `getName` will consult the file system and spot that the file being addressed as "readme" is actually called "README".

Answer (score 4):

You could try `File.getCanonicalPath`. I don't have a Windows box to test this on, so it's just a stab in the dark.

Comment: Heh. Well, if Jon Skeet suggests the same thing then I guess it's not a *totally* wild stab :)